# EF Core (5) navigation property without DB relation

Tags: c#, sql-server, many-to-many, ef-database-first, ef-core-5.0

I have an old database that I can't change now. In the database there are no relation amongst tables. Please see the below DB image. Here three tables which are defines many to many relation but no physically relation (foreign key). With EFCore DB first approach, Now I need to map EFCore models with navigator. I have created the model classes as below,

```
public class Company {
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    [Column("COMPANY_ID")]
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Column("FULL_NAME")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    /*Others properties*/

    public virtual ICollection<TagCompany> TagCompanies { set; get; }
}

public class Tag {
    [Column("TAG_GROUP_ID")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [Column("TAG_ITEM_ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column("TAG_ITEM_NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("TAG_ITEM_DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TagCompany> TagCompanies { set; get; }
}

public class TagCompany {
    [Column("COMPANY_ID")]
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Column("TAG_ITEM_ID")]
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { set; get; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { set; get; }
}
```

And the OnModelCreating methods as below,

```
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasKey(o => o.CompanyId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasKey(o => new { o.GroupId, o.Id });


            modelBuilder.Entity<TagCompany>().HasKey(o => new { o.CompanyId, o.TagId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<TagCompany>().HasOne(s => s.Tag).WithMany(s => s.TagCompanies).HasPrincipalKey(o => new { o.GroupId, o.Id });
            modelBuilder.Entity<TagCompany>().HasOne(s => s.Company).WithMany(s => s.TagCompanies).HasForeignKey(s => s.CompanyId);
            }
```

With above code I am facing below error,

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'TagGroupId'. Invalid column name 'TagId1'. at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at

Any help is appreciate. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Is `TAG.TAG_ITEM_ID` unique?

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, TAG.TAG_ITEM_ID is not unique. As you can see It's composite key with TAG.TAG_GROUP_ID.

Comment: Sure, but it could still be unique. But that means that there's no way to identity which tag is referred to by TAG_COMPANY. I wonder how any existing application deals with this flaw in the data. It also means that you can't define the relationships you want in EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if `Tag.Id` is not unique, you have a hidden one-to-many relationship between `TagCompany` and `Tag`, which requires collection navigation property and generally cannot be mapped to the single `TagCompany.TagId` FK.

You can fool EF that `Tag.Id` is unique by mapping it as [alternate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys), which then would allow you to map `TagCompany.TagId` as many-to-one FK by replacing

```
.HasPrincipalKey(o => new { o.GroupId, o.Id }
```

with

```
.HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id)
```

But now some queries will return incorrect results in the `Tag` data contains duplicate `Id`s. For instance, here

```cs
var companies = db.Set<Company>()
    .Include(e => e.TagCompanies).ThenInclude(e => e.Tag)
    .ToList();

var includedTags = companies
    .SelectMany(e => e.TagCompanies).Select(e => e.Tag)
    .ToList();

var actualTags = db.Set<Company>()
    .SelectMany(e => e.TagCompanies).Select(e => e.Tag)
    .ToList();
```

`actualTags` is correct, and `includedTags` is not (contains less items).

So a better hack which seems to work with EFC 5 would be to configure the many-to-many relationship with the so called skip navigations. Here is the modified model (the essential are the two collection navigation properties):

```cs
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    [Column("COMPANY_ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Column("FULL_NAME")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    /*Others properties*/

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } // <--
}

public class Tag
{
    [Column("TAG_GROUP_ID")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [Column("TAG_ITEM_ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column("TAG_ITEM_NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("TAG_ITEM_DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; } // <--
}

public class TagCompany
{
    [Column("COMPANY_ID")]
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Column("TAG_ITEM_ID")]
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { set; get; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

and the fluent configuration:

```cs
// composite PK
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasKey(e => new { e.GroupId, e.Id });

// M2M relationship and join entity configuration
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Tags)
    .WithMany(e => e.Companies)
    .UsingEntity<TagCompany>(
        j => j.HasOne(e => e.Tag).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.TagId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.Id), // fake alternate key
        j => j.HasOne(e => e.Company).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.CompanyId),
        j => j.HasKey(e => new { e.CompanyId, e.TagId }) // composite PK
    );
```

Now the same test as before

```cs
var companies = db.Set<Company>()
    .Include(e => e.Tags)
    .ToList();

var includedTags = companies
    .SelectMany(e => e.Tags)
    .ToList();

var actualTags = db.Set<Company>()
    .SelectMany(e => e.Tags)
    .ToList();
```

yield one and the same results.

---

Now, the last hack **seems** to work in EFC 5 (not tested with projections and other  non entity returning LINQ queries), but might break in future EFC versions, so use it on your own risk. From the other side, there is no other way to map such db model, so...

Comment: EF: "Sorry, can't do it". Ivan: "What? I'll make you!"

Answer (score 0):

TAG_COMPANY would have to have a TAG_GROUP_ID column to make the EF relationship work.  The Foreign Key in the database is not technically required, but having all the key columns is required.

If TAG.TAG_ITEM_ID is unique, you could configure that as the Key of `Tag`.

Comment: Sorry, we can't change the database schema as it's very old existing database and millions of data already saved.

Comment: You can configure the entity Key to map to any unique index in the database without changing the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug , try this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TagCompany>().HasKey(o => new { o.CompanyId, o.TagId });
```

Comment: Hi @Serge,  Sorry it was a typo. I fix it in the description.

Comment: @Sayem It's ok. I am wondering how this typo could be made. Are typing your code again here instead of copy-paste?

Comment: It's very large tables and classes, I just put here relevant part. It's an very old database and not normalized and bad part is we can't change the DB schema.

Comment: @Sayem You can make some of your classes keyless if you can't find anything better. The only bad thing about this is you  will have to create alot of joins manually instead of using Include.